# $this in Magento phtml files

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I understand that the variable $this is used in object oriented php. I references the current object. Now, looking into phtml files in Magento, how do I know which object is referencing when using the keyword $this.

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way of doing it is to use the get_class method from php.
So, in your phtml right at the begining you can do

```
var_dump(get_class($this));
```

-> this will show you what object/class is in fact pointing this

Another way of doing it is to search in the layout files

For example
- let's say that you have this phtml catalog/product/view.phtml and you want to know who is $this
- firstly, you search for it in the layout files

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
```

- in order to see which class $this is you look at the type attribute -> catalog/product_view and using the magento folder structur you will know that your class is locate in app/code/core/Mage/**Catalog**/Block/**Product**/**View**

Answer (score 4):

In order find the source of `$this`, you need to figure out what the parent block class is. The easiest way to do this is to enable "Template Hints" and "Add Block Names to Hints" in `System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer > Debug`. (You will need to switch to the website or store view to see these options.) The template file is listed at the top left of the block, and the class name at the top right.

Comment: Alternatively you could just `var_dump(get_class($this))`;